# Python Pandas Plot graphs in percentage

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have data of States and Classes as below. I am trying to plot the total, and different percentages using matplotlib.

```
data = [['FL', 2], ['AR', 0], ['CA', 0], ['CA', 1], ['AR', 1], ['FL', 0], ['CA', 0], ['CA', 1], ['AR', 2], ['FL', 1], 
        ['AR', 0], ['FL', 2], ['CA', 1], ['FL', 1], ['AR', 1], ['AR', 2], ['AR', 1], ['FL', 2], ['CA', 2], ['FL', 0], 
        ['FL', 2], ['AR', 2], ['AR', 1], ['FL', 0], ['AR', 1], ['CA', 0], ['CA', 0], ['CA', 2]]
columns = ['State', 'Class']
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=columns)
df.groupby(['State', 'Class']).size()
```

The counts were plotted using the code below:

```
df.groupby(['State', 'Class']).size().to_frame('Size').unstack(level=-1).sort_values([('Size', 0)], ascending=False).plot(kind='bar', rot=45, figsize=(8,8), fontsize=10)
plt.legend(['Class 0', 'Class 1', 'Class 2'], prop ={'size' : 15})
```

Similarly, percentages (state level, class level and overall) need to be plotted as well. Here's what I'm looking for:

- Graph 1 : State on x axis and State level percentage of 'Size' on y axis with bars colored for each class (i.e., 3 bars per state)
- Graph 2 : Class on x axis and Class level percentage  of 'Size' on y axis with bars colored for each state (i.e., 51 bars per class)
- Graph 3 : same as Graph 1 with Overall percentage  of 'Size' on y axis.

Would you please help with how it can be done with an elegant approach ?

Below is my current solution. Need to plot StatePercent, ClassPercent and OverallPercent (Pic#3). My wish is to generate the 3 graphs without creating columns, like how it's done for 'Size' (Pic#2). (In the actual data frame, I have 100s of other columns; so looking for options not to create unnecessary columns if possible. These three columns are needed only for the stats, not for any of the processing)

Pic#1 - the dataframe
[image: Pic#1 - the dataframe]

Pic#2 - Plotting 'Size' without creating a column in df
[image: Pic#2 - Plotting 'Size' without creating a column in df]

Pic#3 - Need to plot StatePercent, ClassPercent and OverallPercent values as calculated below
[image: Pic#3 - Need to plot StatePercent, ClassPercent and OverallPercent values]

Comment: See [ask] and [mre]. It's unclear on 'percentages (state level, class level and overall)', and you should try to do programming for that by yourself at first. Anyway, why are you looking for an 'elegant' one at first? Just solve the problem at first with basic tools. You said 'percentages'. Why not get some kind of sums with ```DataFrame.sum()``` or ```DataFrameGroupBy.sum()``` and divide values?

Comment: Hello relent95, Sorry for not being clear enough. I do have a solution; but I consider it as quite novice. So I'm here in stakoverflow for expert opinion and elegant approaches.
Here is how I'm plotting it now.
`df = df.groupby(['State', 'Class']).size().reset_index(name='Size')
df['StatePercent'] = df.groupby('State')['Size'].transform(lambda x: x/sum(x))
df['ClassPercent'] = df.groupby('Class')['Size'].transform(lambda x: x/sum(x))
df['OverallPercent'] = df['Size'].transform(lambda x:x/sum(x))`
I think there are much better ways to plot without creating columns. Please help.Thanks you.

Comment: You need to add that code into your question. Also you need to define your terms. For example, 'state level percentage' of a state and a class can be defined as 100*(count of records for a state and a class)/(count of records for a class and all states).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your terms are defined like these.

1. State level percentage of a state S and a class C = 100 * (count of records for the state S and the class C) / (count of records for the class C and all states)
2. Class level percentage of a state S and a class C = 100 * (count of records for the state S and the class C) / (count of records for the state S and all classes)
3. Overall percentage of a state S and a class C = 100 * (count of records for the state S and the class C) / (count of records for all states and all classes)

You can use the `apply()` and `sum()` like the following example.

```
df0 = df.groupby(['State', 'Class']).size().to_frame('Size')
df1 = df0.unstack(level=1).apply(lambda row: 100*row/sum(row), axis=1)
df2 = df0.unstack(level=0).apply(lambda row: 100*row/sum(row), axis=1)
df3 = 100*df0.unstack(level=1)/df0.sum().sum()
```

You can plot df1, df2 and df3 for case 1, 2 and 3 respectively.